# What circuit symbol is this? I know its a diode, but the part number leads nowhere

Tags: diodes, symbol

I cant seem to find what type of schottky diode this symbol is representing. The part number listed on this reference schematic leads nowhere. If you could give me an example PN it would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a **bidirectional TVS (transient voltage suppressing) diode**. Used to clamp voltages, particularly ESD spikes.

Although a bidirectional TVS will protect lines that use unipolar voltages, a unidirectional TVS diode will protect such lines more effectively because they will clamp negative spikes closer to GND via forward conduction rather than waiting for the negative spike to get large enough to cause the TVS to break down in reverse.

You can also make a bidirectional TVS diode by placing two unidirectional TVS diodes in series facing opposite directions. That's all a birdirectional TVS diode is, except it's just in a single package instead of two. Don't forget to account for the forward voltage drop of the one diode by subtracting it from the reverse breakdown voltage of the other.

Comment: Thanks! For unidirectional, would you have the anode on the data line and cathode to ground? Thanks

Comment: No, You want cathode on the data line and anode on GND since they work by breaking down in reverse to clamp positive voltages. If you had it as you say, it would be a short from the data line to GND (it would clamp the line to a very low positive voltage...like 0.7V or 1V via forward conduction). You can think of them as zener diodes optimized for pulse power and speed rather than accuracy.

Comment: sweet thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

As [DKNguyen's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/485899/what-circuit-symbol-is-this-i-know-its-a-diode-but-the-part-number-leads-nowhe/485900#485900) said, its a TVS diode, but searching Google for "LESD5VD8LCG-R" gives the manufacturer (with a broken data sheet link, but it has a contact form):

[LESD5VD8LCG-R](https://www.sierraic.com/lesd5vd8lcg)

Comment: Yea, if there is no data sheet I consider it a fake part

Comment: That isn't the manufacturer website. Clicking around that site, you'll find "Sierra IC©. strives to be a world leading independent **distributor** specialist" [emphasis added].

Comment: @ThePhoton I meant it gives the manufacturer name (Lision Technology).